# Wordpress Rewrite Rule Anything

Tags: regex, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm trying to create a plugin that adds an "invite" post type that has an "rewrite" param to prepend "convite" before post slug... The code looks like this:

```php
register_post_type("invite_company", [
    'label' => __("Empresas", "modaladvisorsplugin"),
    'public' => true,
    'supports' => ['title'],
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'show_in_rest' => false,
    'rewrite' => [
        'slug' => "convite",
    ],
    'menu_icon' => "dashicons-building",
]);
```

At this point, all works fine. Next step is to add an rewrite rule to append anything after the post slug, that will be used in template as a query var... So, for example, this url:

`site.com/convite/company/abcdefg`

Must recognize `abcdefg` as a `advisor` query parameter. For this, I've tried this way:

```php
register_post_type("invite_company", [
    'label' => __("Empresas", "modaladvisorsplugin"),
    'public' => true,
    'supports' => ['title'],
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'show_in_rest' => false,
    'rewrite' => [
        'slug' => "convite",
    ],
    'menu_icon' => "dashicons-building",
]);

public function rewrite_rules()
{
    add_rewrite_rule( 
        "convite/([a-z0-9-]+)[/]?$",
        "index.php?post_type=invite_company&advisor=\$matches[1]",
        "top"
    );
}
```

And filtering query_vars as follow:

```php
public function query_vars($vars)
{
    $vars[] = "advisor";
    return $vars;
}
```

Sometime (I don't remember what was in regex), when I tried to access `/convite/some-post-slug/abcde`, the URL was rewritten to `/convite/some-post-slug` (excluding the appended segment).

By the way, isn't working... I think is a regex problem (maybe `convite/([a-z0-9-]+)[/]?$` isn't what I need), but really I don't know what I'm doing wrong, and I'm not an expert in regex...

Can anyone help me?

Comment: In your example, what is "company"? Hard to understand what is the final URL you're trying to achieve here

Comment: did you save permalinks after adding the new rewrite rule?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm fully understanding the requirements, but this might work better. The regex is a bit easier this way, and it should check for both company by itself as well as company with advisor.

```
add_rewrite_rule('convite/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?invite_company=$matches[1]&advisor=$matches[2]', 'top');
add_rewrite_rule('convite/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?invite_company=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

Also, remember to flush rewrite rules before testing (resave permalinks, or run `flush_rewrite_rules();` in your code while testing).